# Nodejs variable undefined after "await"

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I know there are questions like this already.  I promise I've read them; I'm just not getting it.  I have some simple code to get a token for a 3rd-party API service:

```
let tok = '';
const getToken = async () => {
  tok = await btt.get();
  console.log(tok);
};
getToken();
```

`tok` is always `undefined` at the `console.log`.  I thought the whole point of `await` was that your code would pause until that particular promise was resolved or rejected; am I mistaken?  Here's the `get` function:

```
async get () {
  this.paymentGateway.clientToken.generate({
    customerId: '5cdc7405da53494ee0f3bafe'
  }, (err, result) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (result.success) {
        resolve(result.clientToken);
      } else {
        reject(result.errors);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I've been stuck this particular issue for a while and tried a lot of different ways. If someone could help, I'd be grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: next time try not to send your client token ;) (would be a good idea to ask for another one now)

Comment: Your get() is not returning anything

Comment: Ha...that's not a client token.  Its a Mongo objectID from our dev DB.

Comment: tonsteri...get() isn't returning the promise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your async function is not returning a promise. Try this:

```
async get () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.paymentGateway.clientToken.generate({
      customerId: '5cdc7405da53494ee0f3bafe'
    }, (err, result) => {
      if (result.success) {
        resolve(result.clientToken);
      } else {
        reject(result.errors);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

---

An example:

```js
const mockPaymentGateway = {
  clientToken: {
    // a mock that will randomly succeed and fail.
    generate: (_, callback) => callback(null, Math.random() > 0.5 ? {
      success: true,
      clientToken: '<This is a token value.>'
    } : {
      errors: ['We have no moneys.']
    }),
  }
}

// I assume you have other things in your service, but here is an example
class SomeService {
  constructor(paymentGateway) {
    this.paymentGateway = paymentGateway;
  }


  async get() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.paymentGateway.clientToken.generate({
        customerId: '5cdc7405da53494ee0f3bafe'
      }, (err, result) => {
        if (result.success) {
          resolve(result.clientToken);
        } else {
          reject(result.errors);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
// Generating mock data...

const btt = new SomeService(mockPaymentGateway);

let tok = '';
const getToken = async() => {
  try {
    tok = await btt.get();
    console.log(tok);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Errors getting token:', e);
  }
};

document.querySelector('#get-token').addEventListener('click', async() => {
  console.log('Getting token');
  getToken()
});
```

```html
<button id="get-token">Get token</button>
```

Comment: This works!  Thank you!  Question though; I thought my original code returned a promise; what was wrong there?

Comment: @boing you returned a promise to the callback function, you did not return anything from `get()` itself.

Comment: No, your original code called a `this.paymentGateway.generate(options, callback);`. Then it did not return anything, meaning, it returns undefined by default.

Comment: And your callback returned a promise, but you never got the result from the callback itself. Hold on for a better example.

Comment: Ahhh, I get it!  The async call to `generate` was not inside the promise!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your call inside Promise:

```
async get () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.paymentGateway.clientToken.generate({
      customerId: '5cdc7405da53494ee0f3bafe'
    }, (err, result) => {
      if (result.success) {
        resolve(result.clientToken);
      } else {
        reject(result.errors);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: @boing, here is working example https://repl.it/repls/StaidUnderstatedDeals

Answer (score 0):

You never resolved the promise.  Change the last line to this:

```
getToken().catch(console.error);
```